# Perform anti INNER JOIN on two tables

Tags: ms-access, inner-join

I was wondering if there is a quick way to do the following.  As I understand it, an INNER JOIN on a field present in two tables returns information from the two tables having the field and its values in common.  However, what I'm trying to do is to return the table rows that do not meet the INNER JOIN criteria.  So, for example if I had Table 1 as

```
Product     Price
Greens      $2
Beans       $1
Potatoes    $3
Tomatoes    $4
```

and table 2 as

```
Product     Quantity
Potatoes    45
Tomatoes    100
Chickens    27
Turkeys     33
```

what I'm looking to output is

```
Product     Price     Quantity
Greens      $2        NULL
Beans       $1        NULL
Chickens    NULL      27
Turkeys     NULL      33
```

Is this at all possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't clearly say what you want. So you can't reason, code, search or ask. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. When this is clear it will be a faq or two. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use two outer joins, one for products not having a corresponding price (price IS NULL) and one for products not having a corresponding quantity.
I used two separate queries (one for each join).
Next, used UNION to combine the results.

```
SELECT table1.Product, table1.Price, table2.Quantity
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Product = table2.Product
WHERE table2.Quantity IS NULL
ORDER BY table1.Price DESC
UNION
SELECT table2.Product, table1.Price, table2.Quantity
FROM table1 RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.Product = table2.Product
WHERE table1.Price IS NULL
ORDER BY table2.Quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for each of the tables and combine the results with `UNION ALL`:

```
select t1.product, t1.price, null as quantity from table1 as t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where product = t1.product)
union all
select t2.product, null as price, t2.quantity from table2 as t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 where product = t2.product)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it using the `UNION` and `MINUS` operations.
`(SELECT * FROM t1 UNION SELECT * FROM t2)  MINUS SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Product = t2.Product`

Comment: MS Access does not support the `minus` keyword.